# Who's the sweetie?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, steganography

White Day is a day when males return the favours of girls who have given them Valentine's gifts.

Dave, being a presentable and generous specimen of a male, had received numerous Valentines from his many admirers in his different school classes. He had been careful to make sure none of them were forgotten on White Day.

However,Dave felt this day would be the perfect time to declare his love to his crush -a charming blonde in his math class. This would create  a major problem though.

Whilst Dave was single, the competition was friendly enough. However, if Dave were to be claimed in a relationship, the unsuccessful girls would be very jealous. And jealous girls turn into vicious little trolls-so Dave had to find a way to let his girl know that only she could tell.

So he wrote a love note and pinned it up on the common room board. Love poetry is not Dave's major strength, but it did the job. So who is Dave's sweetheart?

***Incredible darling only forever***

***Magnificent eyes,glorious sensuousness***

***and unbeatably brilliant,megapassionate***

***Sweetheart,beautiful,delightful,beloved***

Comment: Do you want to add the steganography tag?

Comment: Ah yes it does seem to be a steggy puzzle.added

Comment: Interesting counter to the trope by logically implying that the blonde is smarter than all the others, able to figure out something they can't without relying on information they're not privy to (e.g. a common experience shared between message sender & recipient).

Comment: So... any update?

Comment: Afraid you're not right. Start at the very beginning,it's a very good place to start...

Comment: hmm... I was thinking the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Let's try:

> Miko.
>
>  Counting the syllables (and assuming unbeatably is 3 syllables rather than 4, regional dialect), the syllable count is:
> 4 2 2 3 4 1 3 4 1 4 3 5 2 3 3 3

For some reason I can't get the matrix form for that, but:

> Written as a 4x4 matrix, and then transposed (Math class and all), the sum of each row becomes 13, 9, 11, 15 which spells out Miko.

It's a bit of a push, but I thought I'd try.